# Proof of (in)distinguishability based on DDH/CDH/DL

Tags: diffie-hellman, discrete-logarithm, distinguisher

I am wondering whether or not it is known that the following problem is computationally infeasible while working in a group for which the DDH (or CDH or DL) assumption holds (as usual, g is a group generator):
Given the input tuple $(g, g^{\alpha_1}, g^{\alpha_2}, g^{y}, g^{z})$ where $z \in \{y \alpha_1, y \alpha_2\}$, the desired output is $g^{\alpha_i}$ (or simply $i$) such that $z = y\alpha_i$.

If it is not known, I would appreciate any suggestions for a reduction based proof.

Comment: This is tightly equivalent to DDH.

Answer (score 1):

The two given tuples are computationally indistinguishable. Here's a proof

Let tuples $T_1=(g, g^{\alpha_1}, g^{\alpha_2}, g^y, g^{\alpha_1y})$ and $T_2=(g,  g^{\alpha_1}, g^{\alpha_2}, g^y, g^{\alpha_2y})$

Lets take a tuple $T_3=(g, g^{\alpha_1}, g^{\alpha_2}, g^y, g^r)$ where $r \overset{$}\leftarrow  
 \mathcal{R}$. That is, for the purpose of the proof we generate a tuple with the last element being a random element of the group.

It's easy to see that $T_1 \approx T_3$ ($\approx$: notation for compuational indistinguishability) because of DDH assumption. Same way, $T_2 \approx T_3$ as well. Since we know that [computational indistinguishability is transitive](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall07/cos433/lec4.pdf), that means $T_1 \approx T_2$.

Comment: One may want to note when reading this answer that computational indistinguishability is in general only transitive for a constant number of hops.

Comment: @SEJPM: Could you explain why? I always thought it also worked for poly-many hops (this is how, for example, the hybrid argument works). The discussion in [this](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs6830/2009fa/scribes/lec08.pdf) lecture note also seems to agree.

Comment: @Occams_Trimmer It only works for poly-many hops if all the hops can be bound by the same negligble function. An example for a family of functions where each is negligible but the sum isn't is: $\varepsilon_i(n)=\begin{cases}1&i\geq n\\0&\text{else}\end{cases}$. Obviously each is individually neglgigble but if you consider $$p(n)=\sum^n_i \varepsilon_i(n)$$ it is obviously constantly $1$ and thus not negligible. Though also note that most proofs where an author errornously assumed that poly-many hops can be done can usually be fixed.

Comment: In the non-uniform model, the assumptions (finitely many) allow transitivity to go through for poly-many hops. In the uniform model, a strict proof is written as a probabilistic reduction and "poly-many hops" do not exist in the proof and are a pedagody device. Usually the proof can be uniform (i.e., written as probabilistic reduction) and it's routine to use "poly-many hops" exposition (or perhaps the authors don't care about uniform security).